# How to determine key name of outer dictionary knowing values in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, nested-datalist

So I have a dictionary like below:

```
{
  'outerkey1': 
    {'innerkey1': 'value1'},
  'outerkey2': 
    {'innerkey2': 'value2'}
}
```

I know the value of `'value2'`, which I can determine the key name is `'innerkey2'`, but how can I know it's from `'outerkey2'`?

Comment: Can you give a bit more details regarding your use case, what you seem to want is a path to a value, correct? It's time expensive to find it, so it's probably better to have a look at your code and see how you can preserve it when you access the value.

Comment: So you want to find the 'parent' of a nested dictionary?

Comment: Are more than one outerkeys with the same innerkey?

Comment: That's not a valid dictionary

Comment: Why do you want to do such a thing? Please provide some context for the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop through the dictionary:

```
my_dict = {'outerkey1':{'innerkey1':'value1'}, 'outerkey2':{'innerkey2':'value2'}}

lookup = "value2"

for key, val in my_dict.items():
    for x, y in val.items():
        if y == lookup:
            print(key)
```